# Unwear winterbash hats

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

Is there any way to unwear winterbash hats?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just click on that hat again to un-wear it.

[image]

Comment: Tried it before and it didn't seem to work. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: You don't want to wear that bra? Seems reasonable :D

Answer (score 7):

what you just need to click again to un-wear

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Click the hat again in the hat selection dialog. That's all you have to do.

For example, I just de-hatted myself on StackApps:

[image]

Comment: You mad de-hatter, you.