# How to remove Winter Bash hat from my profile picture

Tags: support, stack-overflow, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unwear winterbash hats with only one hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159230/unwear-winterbash-hats-with-only-one-hat)

In Stackoverflow I added a Winter Bash **Hat** to my profile picture. How can I remove that again?

Comment: just click on it again - this worked for me

Comment: Worked well. Thanks.