# How do I deselect my hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unwear winterbash hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159230/unwear-winterbash-hats)

Please close as a duplicate if your search skills are more successful than mine at finding where this question has already been asked.

How do I *deselect* a hat in my profile?  I accidentally selected a hat, and now the only option I can find is to select a different hat. I want no hat!

Comment: Wait for Jan 5th