# How do I take off my hat?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

How do I take off my hat on one site only?

I see a button for “take off your hats everywhere”, and I can select a different hat on a site. How do I go bare-headed (well, bare, um, let's go for hatless) on one particular site?

[Last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159230/unwear-winterbash-hats) I could click my hat again, but it isn't working this year.

Comment: You don't. That's the beauty of it. Once you pick a hat, you're stuck with it until our Evil Overlords decide we're done poking fun at ourselves and others. If you don't want to wear a hat, don't put it on. `:-)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've changed the behavior such that checking "only on this site" also changes "take off your hats everywhere" to "take off your hat on this site".